# Table not rendered using ajax_render in ctools modal window

Tags: ajax, chaos-tool-suite, javascript

This is a continuation from [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/112612/using-ajax-with-pager-in-ctools-modal-window),where I'm wanting to display a form for searching Apache Solr and displaying the results with a pager. I've modified my approach to have the search run from the page function if there are values in the form. As I have it now, the search is run and results are returned just fine, but for some reason I can't get the table to render when I pass a render array through ajax_render().  Here's the relevant code:

```
/**
 * Page callback for imgsearch modal popup window.
 */
function imgsearch_page($ajax, $id, $a, $b) {
  if ($ajax) {
    //Load the modal library and add the modal javascript.
    ctools_include('ajax');
    ctools_include('modal');

    $form_state = array(
      'ajax' => TRUE,
      'title' => t('Image Search Form'),
      'next_field_id' => $id,
    );

    // Use ctools to generate ajax instructions for the browser to create
    // a form in a modal popup.
    $search_form = ctools_modal_form_wrapper('imgsearch_form', $form_state);
    if ($search_form[0]) {
      $output = $search_form;
    }
    else {
      $build['search_form'] = $search_form;
    }
    // If the form has been submitted, there may be additional instructions
    // such as dismissing the modal popup.
    if (!empty($form_state['ajax_commands'])) {
      $output = $form_state['ajax_commands'];
    }

    if($form_state['values']['search_terms'] != '') {
      // See apachesolr_saved_searches_get_results() in ozmosys project for code to run solr search.
      $results = nb_image_search_search($form_state['values']);

      if (is_array($results['images']) && count($results['images'] > 0)) {
        $next_field_id = $form_state['next_field_id'];
        // Create object to store file and target field info. To be stored in ctools cache.
        $file_info = new stdClass();
        // Generate the field name.  field_images is a multivalue field collection, so we just need the next available option
        // in the $field_images['und'] array. The second number (for field_image) will always be 0 since it
        // is a single value field.
        $file_info->fieldname['url'] = '#edit-field-images-und-' . $next_field_id . '-field-image-und-0-imgsearch-file-url';
        $file_info->fieldname['person'] = '#edit-field-images-und-' . $next_field_id . '-field-person-und-0-value';
        $file_info->fieldname['organization'] = '#edit-field-images-und-' . $next_field_id . '-field-organization-und-0-value';
        $file_info->fieldname['year'] = '#edit-field-images-und-' . $next_field_id . '-field-year-und-0-value';

        $file_info->fids = array();

        // Theme the results as a table.
        $header = array(t('Image'), t('File Name'), t('Add to field'));
        $rows = array();
        foreach ($results['images'] as $image) {
          // Create image style derivative for each image.
          $imagestyle = array(
            'style_name' => 'thumbnail',
            'path' => $image['filepath'] . $image['filename'],
            'width' => '',
            'height' => '',
            'alt' => '',
            'title' => $image['filename'],
          );
          $styled_image = theme('image_style', $imagestyle);
          $fid = $image['fid'];

          $rows[] = array(
            'image' => $styled_image,
            'name' => $image['filename'],
            'add' => ctools_ajax_text_button("select", "imgsearch/nojs/imgadd/" . $fid . '/' . $next_field_id, t('Select')),
          );

          $file_info->fids[$fid] = $image['filename'];

          // Cache values for Person, Organization, and Year if they exist.
          foreach (array('person', 'organization', 'year') as $field) {
            if (isset($image[$field])) {
              $file_info->meta[$fid][$field] = $image[$field];
            }
          }
        }
        //Cache image name in ctools object cache so it can be used later in nb_image_search_image_add()
        ctools_include('object-cache');
        ctools_object_cache_set('imgsearch', 'imgsearch_' . $next_field_id, $file_info);

        // Create a render array ($build) which will be themed as a table with a
        // pager.
        $build['imgsearch_table'] = array(
          '#theme' => 'table',
          '#header' => $header,
          '#rows' => $rows,
          '#empty' => t('There were no matching results found'),
        );

        // Attach the pager theme.
      /*pager_default_initialize($results['total_found'], $results['rows']);
        $build['imgsearch_pager'] = array('#theme' => 'pager'); */

      }
      else {
        $build['no_results'] = array(
          'markup' => '<div class="no-results>No images found</div>',
        );
      }
    }

    if (!$output) {
      $output = $build;
    }

    // Return the ajax instructions to the browser via ajax_render().
    print ajax_render($output);
    drupal_exit();
  }
  else {
    return drupal_get_form('imgsearch_form', $id);
  }
}
```

What happens is that if the search has been run, the search form is in $build as the $form array, and the second array in $build is imgsearch_table, which is a render array with #theme, #rows, and #header. However, I can't get the table to be rendered or displayed anywhere. I've been banging my head on this for way too long. What do I have to do to get my table to be rendered in my modal window, along with the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got the table to render fine every time. Updated code:

```
function imgsearch_page($ajax, $id, $a, $b) {
  if ($ajax) {
    //Load the modal library and add the modal javascript.
    ctools_include('ajax');
    ctools_include('modal');

    $form_state = array(
      'ajax' => TRUE,
      'title' => t('Image Search Form'),
      'next_field_id' => $id,
    );

    // Use ctools to generate ajax instructions for the browser to create
    // a form in a modal popup.
    $search_form = ctools_modal_form_wrapper('imgsearch_form', $form_state);

    if (($form_state['executed'] && $form_state['ajax']) || isset($_GET['page'])) {
      // If the form has been submitted, there may be additional instructions
      // such as dismissing the modal popup.
      if (!empty($form_state['ajax_commands'])) {
        $output = $form_state['ajax_commands'];
      }

      if ($form_state['values']['search_terms'] != '' || isset($_GET['search_terms'])) {
        $page_num = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 0;
        // See apachesolr_saved_searches_get_results() in ozmosys project for code to run solr search.
        if ($_GET['search_terms']) {
          $form_state['values']['search_terms'] = $_GET['search_terms'];
        }
        $results = nb_image_search_search($form_state['values'], $page_num);

        if (is_array($results['images']) && count($results['images'] > 0)) {
          $next_field_id = $form_state['next_field_id'];
          // Create object to store file and target field info. To be stored in ctools cache.
          $file_info = new stdClass();
          // Generate the field name.  field_images is a multivalue field collection, so we just need the next available option
          // in the $field_images['und'] array. The second number (for field_image) will always be 0 since it
          // is a single value field.
          $file_info->fieldname['url'] = '#edit-field-images-und-' . $next_field_id . '-field-image-und-0-imgsearch-file-url';
          $file_info->fieldname['person'] = '#edit-field-images-und-' . $next_field_id . '-field-person-und-0-value';
          $file_info->fieldname['organization'] = '#edit-field-images-und-' . $next_field_id . '-field-organization-und-0-value';
          $file_info->fieldname['year'] = '#edit-field-images-und-' . $next_field_id . '-field-year-und-0-value';

          $file_info->fids = array();

          // Theme the results as a table.
          $header = array(t('Image'), t('File Name'), t('Add to field'));
          $rows = array();
          foreach ($results['images'] as $image) {
            // Create image style derivative for each image.
            $imagestyle = array(
              'style_name' => 'thumbnail',
              'path' => $image['filepath'] . $image['filename'],
              'width' => '',
              'height' => '',
              'alt' => '',
              'title' => $image['filename'],
            );
            $styled_image = theme('image_style', $imagestyle);
            $fid = $image['fid'];

            $rows[] = array(
              'image' => $styled_image,
              'name' => $image['filename'],
              'add' => ctools_ajax_text_button("select", "imgsearch/nojs/imgadd/" . $fid . '/' . $next_field_id, t('Select')),
            );

            $file_info->fids[$fid] = $image['filename'];

            // Cache values for Person, Organization, and Year if they exist.
            foreach (array('person', 'organization', 'year') as $field) {
              if (isset($image[$field])) {
                $file_info->meta[$fid][$field] = $image[$field];
              }
            }
          }
          //Cache image name in ctools object cache so it can be used later in nb_image_search_image_add()
          ctools_include('object-cache');
          ctools_object_cache_set('imgsearch', 'imgsearch_' . $next_field_id, $file_info);

          // Create a render array ($build) which will be themed as a table with a
          // pager.
          $build['search_form'] = isset($search_form[0]) ? drupal_build_form('imgsearch_form', $form_state) : $search_form;
          $build['imgsearch_table'] = array(
            '#theme' => 'table',
            '#header' => $header,
            '#rows' => $rows,
            '#empty' => t('There were no matching results found'),
          );

          // Attach the pager theme.
          $pager = pager_default_initialize($results['total_found'], $results['rows']);
          $build['imgsearch_pager'] = array(
            '#theme' => 'pager',
            '#parameters' => array(
              'search_terms' => $form_state['values']['search_terms'],
              //TODO: add params for Person, Organization, and Year.
              ),
          );

          $form_state['values']['title'] = t('Search Results');
          $output = ctools_modal_form_render($form_state['values'], $build);

          print ajax_render($output);
          drupal_exit();
        }
        else {
          $build['no_results'] = array(
            'markup' => '<div class="no-results>No images found</div>',
          );
        }
      }
    }
    elseif (!isset($output)) {
      $output = ctools_modal_form_wrapper('imgsearch_form', $form_state);
      // Return the ajax instructions to the browser via ajax_render().
      print ajax_render($output);
      drupal_exit();
    }
  }
  else {
    return drupal_get_form('imgsearch_form', $id);
  }
}
```

To be honest, I didn't really change anything in regards to the table generation, so I'm suspecting another change I made fixed it.